# Reverse calculation on calculated fields (overwrite) Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculated-field

I have the following product information on a page. (see image).

[Product info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18zPn.png)

the fields Profit, GP% (grossprofit) and Mark Up % initially are empty. But when one clicks on the edit button, these fields are calculated (on the fly) filled in based on the values in Price, Vat Rate, Case Cost, Unit Cost.

[Product info image - after clicking edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR2cx.png)

Now when one edits the "**Price, Case Cost or Vat Rate fields**", the profit, gp and mark up adjust accordingly ( i.e the previously empty fields before edit).

This is the code that was used to achieve this functionality.

```
<script>
    function calculate()
    {
        //Fields that are used for calculations (declare variables)
        var casecost = parseFloat($('#q_casecost').val());
        var casesize = parseFloat($('#q_casesize').val());
        var price = parseFloat($('#q_sellprice').val());
        var profit = parseFloat($('#q_profit').val());    
        var unitcost = parseFloat($('#q_unitcost')); 
        var vatrate = parseFloat($('#vat_guid option:selected').text());  //dropdownlist            
        var markup = parseFloat($('#q_markup').val());                      

        //Calculations
        var unitcost = casecost / casesize; // get unitcost from casecost FIELD and casesize FIELD      

        var markuprate = ((price - unitcost) / unitcost) * 100;

        //var markupvalue = (markuprate / 100) * unitcost;

        var price = ((markuprate / 100) * unitcost) + unitcost;             

        var profit = (price - unitcost) - ((vatrate / 100) * price);

        var grossprofit = (profit / price) * 100;          

        //set results (calculations) to the updating fields
        if (isNaN(casecost) || isNaN(casesize) || isNaN(vatrate)) { return; }
        $('#q_casecost').val(casecost.toFixed(2)); 
        $('#q_unitcost').val(unitcost.toFixed(2));            
        $('#q_profit').val(profit.toFixed(2));
        $('#q_grossprofit').val(grossprofit.toFixed(2));            
        $('#q_sellprice').val(price.toFixed(2));
        $('#q_markup').val(markuprate.toFixed(2));             
    }               

    $(document).ready(function () {
        calculate(); // calculate on page load  

        //calculate every time these following fields change || monitor the fields that affect changes             
        $('#vat_guid').change(calculate); //dropdownlist value sent to calculate
        $('#q_casecost').change(calculate);
        $('#q_casesize').change(calculate);
        //$('#q_unitcost').change(calculate); //for REVERSE calculation of case cost
        $('#q_profit').change(calculate);
        $('#q_markup').change(calculate);
        $('#q_sellprice').change(calculate);             
        $(price).val(calculate);
        $(unitcost).change(calculate);
        $(profit).change(calculate);  
        $(markuprate).change(calculate);    
        //$(markupvalue).change(calculate);                        
    });
</script>
```

Now the next thing I am trying to achieve, is to be able to type in MARK UP field and have the profit, gp and PRICE adjust accordingly. For example if one wants to see what price they should charge if they want say 100% markup, then have the the price field update accordingly.

At the present moment, if I type any value in the Mark Up field, it reverts back to the calculated value and doesn't change to affect the price. I already have the calculation for my price based on mark up value in the code here

```
 var price = ((markuprate / 100) * unitcost) + unitcost;
```

What am I missing to make this functionality possible?

Comment: If I get you correct, you want to calculate markup if price is changed, and price if markup is changed? Currently you have only one calculation for whatever field changes, you need to detect which field changed and then apply the right calculation.

Comment: Currently you are calculating markuprate from the price, THEN calculate price from the just calculated markuprate. That's why changing the markuprate input doesn't do anything. You need to check which input was changed, and then calculate markuprate by price or price by markuprate.

Comment: thanks for the hint @Danmoreng, I was able to wrap the price calculation in this 
$('#q_markup').change(function calculate() {

    });
and it worked.

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Comment: Overwrite is what I meant to type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this might help someone who comes accross this issue.

Within

```
function calculate()
 {
   ----
 }
```

at the end/bottom (order of items seems to be important with jquery), after setting original calculations to updating fields I added a changed (event) function for the mark_up textbox as follows - and that changed event then updates its appropriate textboxes with new updated / calculations

```
//REVERSE CALCULATIONS
            //calculate new price, profit and GP, WHEN NEW MARKUP VALUE IS TYPED
            $('#q_markup').change(function calculate() {

                var markuprateChanged = parseFloat($('#q_markup').val());
                //alert("Mark up rate changed to " + markuprateChanged);
                var price = ((markuprateChanged / 100) * unitcost) + unitcost;
                $('#item_q_sellprice').val(price.toFixed(2));
                //alert("Price is " + price);

                var newPrice = parseFloat($('#item_q_sellprice').val());
                var profitChanged = (newPrice - unitcost) - ((vatrate / 100) * newPrice);
                //alert("Profit is " + profitChanged);
                $('#q_profit').val(profitChanged.toFixed(2));

                var newGrossProfit = (profitChanged / newPrice) * 100;
                //alert("Grossprofit changed to " + newGrossProfit);
                $('#q_grossprofit').val(newGrossProfit.toFixed(2));
            });
```

So one can then change price it will update mark up and other appropriate fields, then if one changes Mark it will reverse calculate price and other appropriate fields.

Full code is as follows, so you can see where this funtion was added

```
<script>
        function calculate()
        {
            //Fields that are used for calculations (declare variables)
            var casecost = parseFloat($('#item_Casecost').val());
            var casesize = parseFloat($('#item_Casesize').val());
            var price = parseFloat($('#item_q_sellprice').val());
            var profit = parseFloat($('#q_profit').val());
            var unitcost = parseFloat($('#q_unitcost').val());
            var vatrate = parseFloat($('#vat_guid option:selected').text());  //dropdownlist
            var markuprateChanged = parseFloat($('#q_markup').val());

            //Calculations
            var unitcost = casecost / casesize; // get unitcost from casecost FIELD and casesize FIELD

            var markuprate = ((price - unitcost) / unitcost) * 100;

            //var markupvalue = (markuprate / 100) * unitcost;

            //var price = ((markuprateChanged / 100) * unitcost) + unitcost;
            var price = parseFloat($('#item_q_sellprice').val());
            //alert("Price is " + price);

            var profit = (price - unitcost) - ((vatrate / 100) * price);

            var grossprofit = (profit / price) * 100;

            //set results (calculations) to the updating fields
            if (isNaN(casecost) || isNaN(casesize) || isNaN(vatrate)) { return; }
            $('#item_Casecost').val(casecost.toFixed(2));
            $('#q_unitcost').val(unitcost.toFixed(2));
            $('#q_profit').val(profit.toFixed(2));
            $('#q_grossprofit').val(grossprofit.toFixed(2));
            $('#item_q_sellprice').val(price.toFixed(2));
            $('#q_markup').val(markuprate.toFixed(2));

            //REVERSE CALCULATIONS
            //calculate new price, profit and GP, WHEN NEW MARKUP VALUE IS TYPED
            $('#q_markup').change(function calculate() {

                var markuprateChanged = parseFloat($('#q_markup').val());
                //alert("Mark up rate changed to " + markuprateChanged);
                var price = ((markuprateChanged / 100) * unitcost) + unitcost;
                $('#item_q_sellprice').val(price.toFixed(2));
                //alert("Price is " + price);

                var newPrice = parseFloat($('#item_q_sellprice').val());
                var profitChanged = (newPrice - unitcost) - ((vatrate / 100) * newPrice);
                //alert("Profit is " + profitChanged);
                $('#q_profit').val(profitChanged.toFixed(2));

                var newGrossProfit = (profitChanged / newPrice) * 100;
                //alert("Grossprofit changed to " + newGrossProfit);
                $('#q_grossprofit').val(newGrossProfit.toFixed(2));
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            calculate(); // calculate on page load

            //calculate everytime these following fields change || monitor the fields that affect changes
            $('#vat_guid').change(calculate); //dropdownlist value sent to calculate
            $('#item_Casecost').change(calculate);
            $('#item_Casesize').change(calculate);
            //$('#q_unitcost').change(calculate); //for REVERSE calculation of case cost
            $('#q_profit').change(calculate);
            $('#q_markup').change(calculate);
            $('#item_q_sellprice').change(calculate);
            //$(price).val(calculate);
            $(unitcost).change(calculate);
            $(profit).change(calculate);
            $(markuprate).change(calculate);
            //$(markupvalue).change(calculate);
        });
    </script>
```